# Include path in pdfpages

Tags: pdfpages

My TeX file is in `C:\Users\ustjo\Desktop\Finance Report\2017\Report`

While the pdf file is in `C:\Users\ustjo\Desktop\Finance Report\2017`

I tried `\includepdf{C:/Users/ustjo/Desktop/Finance Report/2017/DecReport.pdf}`.

It does not work. It said

```
Package pdfpages Error: Cannot find file `C:/Users/ustjo/Desktop/Finance Report/2017/DecReport.pdf'.

...Desktop/Finance Report/2017/DecReport.pdf}`
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you try with a relative path instead of an absolut one? `\includepdf{../DecReport.pdf}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason is that the file path includes a space. This is not supported by package `graphics` by default that is used by package `pdfpages`. Adding package `grffile` should solve this issue:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

Comment: \includepdf[page=-, width = \linewidth]{C:/Users/ustjo/Desktop/Finance Report/2017/U9171331_201712_201712.pdf}

When I tried this, it said Missing $ inserted. ...ce Report/2017/U9171331_201712_201712.pdf}

Why is that?

Comment: @JOHN A possible reason is that package `grffile` is not loaded before `pdfpages`.

Answer (score 1):

Heikos comment above is worth an answer in bold print, because the manual of grffile doesn't state that:

---

### **Load `grffile` before `pdfpages`**, otherwise it will not work!

I just encountered this, because I used pdfpages, got the usual message

> Missing $ inserted

added the grffile package behind pdfpages to my preamble and the error remained!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by replacing the Windows backslashes with two forward slashes:

```
C:\Users\ustjo\Desktop\Finance Report\2017\Report
```

Becomes

```
C://Users//ustjo\Desktop\Finance Report\2017\Report
```